# Image Path is not picking when uploaded the files on ftp server

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to show the image on the web-page.

```
<div float="right" width="30%">
<center><img src="jatinkhurana_image.jpg"/></center>
</div>
```

The above code is from an .html file. My image is also in the same directory in which the html file.

It's working fine when i am running the same when all the html file and image file is in my local directory.

Now I have uploaded all the files in ftp server.Everything else is working fine except it's not showing the image on webPage.

Things that I have tried...
I have logged on to that server and checked file is there or not.... file was there.
I have checked for the file name which is also right.

I don't know why this is not showing the image.

If anyone know, please help me !!!

Comment: cehck the console frrom the browser's inspect element option. If there is an error you will find that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AtanuCSE .... It was a problem of file permission... In my local system I am running with the sudo user which has the permission to read the file so it's working fine here... but on ftp I don't have sudo user permission so it was not working... now I have changed the permission of file according to my need and everything becomes perfect..... thanks a ton for telling me about browser's Inspect element......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser console an inspect that image element. When you find that image copy it's `src` attribute and paste it in new tab and check if you see the picture or not. If you do not  see the picture you must have some broken link to the image, if you see the image in new tab disable all the extensions of your browser like ad-blocks etc and let me know.
EDIT:
Also check if that, that place is blank or the broken image shows up. ( Like chrome loads a tiny broken image if the url is wrong )